# Swift - trimming video and crop to square cpu usage

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, crop

I have a function which take as input a video url and on completion has an output Url of the edited video.

Basically the function create a square shape video and if the video length is more than 30 seconds cut it to be 30 seconds length.

Here's the function:

```
func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
    let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL as URL, options: nil)
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
        handler(nil)
        return
    }
     let clipVideoTrack = urlAsset.tracks( withMediaType: AVMediaType.video ).first! as AVAssetTrack
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize( width: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height )
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60, 30))


    let transform1: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, y: (clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width - clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height) / 2)
    let transform2 = transform1.rotated(by: .pi/2)
    let finalTransform = transform2


    transformer.setTransform(finalTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)

    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

    let timescale = urlAsset.duration.timescale
    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(urlAsset.duration)
    if (duration < 31.0) {
        print("minore")
    } else {
        let startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, timescale)
        let stopTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30, timescale)
        let exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime)
        exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange
        print("maggiore")
    }

    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
        handler(exportSession)
    }
}
```

So far I have tested it only on the simulator.
The function works fine, but I have noticed that the usage of cpu is very hight. It reached 300% and more. While memory usage got up to 414 MB.
Am I missing something? Is that how is supposed to be or am I making some mistake? Is there a way to reduce the cpu usage and Consequently the waiting time.
I am new to swift and this is the first time I work with video and AVFoundation.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find why the CPU is so high?